# How to send email in post_save without asking user to wait in form submission?

Tags: python, django

Here is my post_save method:

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

@receiver(post_save, sender=SubmissionDetails)
def create_submission_email(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        data = sync_to_async(call_submssion_email(instance))

def call_manuscript_submssion_email(instance):
    print("Hi")
    message = '''Submitted with the title, <br>
    {0}'''.format(instance.title)
    subject = 'Article Submitted'
    to_address = 'example@gmail.com'
    from_address = "from@mail.example.com"
    msg = EmailMessage(
                    subject, message,from_address,[to_address]
                    )
    msg.content_subtype = "html"
    msg.send()
```

The problem is while submitting the form, the user has to wait till email is sent to see the results. I am using django 3.0 with some async support.

Answer (score 1):

**Asynchronous support**

**New in Django 3.0**

> Django has developing support for asynchronous (“async”) Python, but
>   does not yet support asynchronous views or middleware; they will be
>   coming in a future release.
>
> There is limited support for other parts of the async ecosystem;
>   namely, Django can natively talk ASGI, and some async safety support.

[Django Asynchronous support official](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/)

---

**You can use** [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) for your asynchronous code.

You can also check [How are Django channels different than celery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620969/how-are-django-channels-different-than-celery/56087994#56087994)

Comment: I know about channels, but unable to find out how to handle this case with channels documentation.  Channel too uses from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

Comment: Maybe I need Celery to perform long-running background tasks

Comment: You can use Celery.